# Get which template being in use within WordPress-admin

Tags: wp-admin

I want to get the template in the theme which being in use of the current edited post(_type)/Page.

Lets say im editing a single Post, Then i want to retrive that it using the template `single.php`

And if im editing a Custom Post Type that have its own `single-{post_type}.php` i want to retrive that.

How can i archive that? are there any global variables that store this information?

I know that pages saves it as meta_data.

I dont have mutch to go with but i have been looking att `get_query_template` and `locate_template` but i need something in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this isn't available in admin. You can take a look at my profile, go to my github page and grab the ["current admin info" plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info). But this won't help you much.

This would show you the template name:

```
get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );
```

On the front end you can use the following plugin, that will display that info (it's from another question).

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#10537) »kaiser« Get Template file name */

if ( ! class_exists( 'wpse10537_template_name' ) )
{
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'wpse10537_template_name', 'init' ) );

class wpse10537_template_name
{
    protected static $instance;

    public $stack;

    public static function init()
    {
        is_null( self :: $instance ) AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( is_admin() )
            return;

        add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'is_parent_template' ), 0 );
        add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'get_template_file' ) );
        add_action( 'template_include', array( $this, 'get_template_name' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'get_template_name' ), 100 );
    }

    public function get_template_name( $file )
    {
        if ( 'template_include' === current_filter() )
        {
            $this->to_stack(
                 "Template file"
                ,basename( $file )
            );
            return $file;
        }

        // Return static var on echo call outside of filter
        if (
            current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
            AND defined( 'WP_DEBUG' )
            AND WP_DEBUG 
            )
        {
            return printf(
                 '<div><p style="text-align:center;">%s</p></div>'
                ,implode( " &ndash; ", $this->stack )
            );
        }
    }

    public function get_template_file()
    {
        if ( ! is_post_type_hierarchical( get_post_type() ) )
            return;

        $slug = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );
        if ( ! strstr( $slug, "/" ) )
            return $this->to_stack( "Template", $slug );

        // Subdirectory info
        $this->to_stack(
             "Subdirectory"
            ,strstr( $slug, "/", true )
        );

        $this->to_stack(
             "Template (in subdirectory)"
            ,str_replace( "/", "", strstr( $slug, "/" ) )
        );
    }

    public function is_parent_template()
    {
        if ( ! is_null( wp_get_theme()->parent ) )
            return $this->to_stack( 'from parent theme' );

        $this->to_stack( 'from current/child theme' );
    }

    public function to_stack( $part, $item = '' )
    {
        $this->stack[] = "{$part}: {$item}";
    }
} // END Class wpse10537_template_name

} // endif;
```

If all this doesn't help as starting point, then please take a look at [all the related answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=template+post+meta).

Comment: @PontusAbrahamsson Could you update my answer with what you finally used (for later readers)? Thanks.

Comment: @PontusAbrahamsson Mods denied the edit. I'll move it to another answer, later on correct it.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer was originally an edit of the OP to my other answer. I'll correct the code later on.*

So i ended up with a pretty simple solution. This answer did get me in the right direction.

I don't now if this is the best way to do it but it fills my requirements:

```
if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' )
{

    $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );

    // Check page-templates, if not set -> page.php
    if ( $post->post_type == 'page' && ( empty( $template ) || 'default' == $template ) )
    {
        $template = 'page.php';
    }
    elseif( empty( $template ) )
    {
        // Check single-templates, single-{post_type}.php -> single.php order
        if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH .'/single-'. $post->post_type .'.php' ) ) {
            $template = 'single-'. $post->post_type .'.php';
        }
        elseif ( ( $post->post_type == 'attachment' || $post->post_type == 'page' ) && file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH .'/'. $post->post_type .'.php' ) )
        {
            $template = $post->post_type .'.php';
        }
        elseif( $post->post_type == 'attachment' )
        {
            $template = '';
        }
        else
        {
            $template = 'single.php';
        }
    }

    // Read the file
    $file = implode( '', file( TEMPLATEPATH .'/' . $template ) );

    // Get the tags in the template, (Blocks Areas: Left, Right)
    if ( preg_match_all( '|Block Areas:(.*)$|mi', $file, $name ) )
    {
        $defined_areas = explode( ',', strtolower( $name[1][0] ) );
        $defined_areas = array_map( 'trim', $defined_areas);
    }
}
```